# Continue only if one OR another condition is met

Tags: java, android, logic, onclicklistener

I have an app that is basically a survey activity. Some questions require that one set of conditions OR another set be filled out before continuing.

When the user presses yes they get one set of EditText fields, if they press no they get a different set. Either choice enables the same continue button, but I need to check that just one of the two sets are filled out before continuing to the next activity.

```
    bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myYesSection.isShown() && valueCombined.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the combined score.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (myNoSection.isShown() && valueOne.getText().toString().isEmpty() || valueTwo.getText().toString().isEmpty() || valueThree.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Intent toNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionThree.class);
                startActivity(toNextActivity);
            }
        }
    });
```

In action, if the *valueCombined* is filled out, the toast comes up to *"Please fill out all fields."* and the user does not go to the next activity. If the *valueCombined* is filled out, I don't need the other fields filled out.

Filling out *valueOne, valueTwo,* and *valueThree* allows the next activity to be opened, but a toast to *"Please enter the combined score."*

What must I change so the button press requires only one of the two conditions to continue?

**Update Working code** Thanks @Andreas for the lesson. This checks exactly what I need, and does not pop the wrong toast if the wrong set of conditions are on display:

```
   bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int count = 0;
            if (combinedValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                if (myYesSection.isShown()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter combined score.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (valueOne.getText().toString().isEmpty() || valueTwo.getText().toString().isEmpty() || valueThree.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                if (myNoSection.isShown()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1){
                Intent toNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionThree.class);
                startActivity(toNextActivity);
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Andreas much appreciated, I will look there. I do not know how I did not come across that on my own (that's what I would have named the condition hah), my search had me thinking it should be a switch case scenario.

Comment: Will this work as I am using getText().toString()? Or must I somehow represent the fields being filled out in boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have e.g. 3 conditions, and you want to do something only if exactly 1 of them is true, count the number of true conditions:

```
int count = 0;
if (condition1)
    count++;
if (condition2)
    count++;
if (condition3)
    count++;
if (count == 1) {
    // Yay!
}
```

Or use ternary operators to shorten it:

```
if (1 == (condition1 ? 1 : 0) +
         (condition2 ? 1 : 0) +
         (condition3 ? 1 : 0)) {
    // Yay!
}
```

If you only have 2 conditions to check, use the **Exclusive-OR** operator:

```
if (condition1 ^ condition2) {
    // Yay!
}
```

JLS [15.22.2. Boolean Logical Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) defines the operator as:

> result value is `true` if the operand values are different; otherwise, the result is `false`.

Comment: Works like a charm! You've made my day Andreas.